# make functions module for reuse

Tags: javascript, jquery

without using any plugin how do I make my function module between 2 `$(document).ready(function(){});`

I can do it by declaring it as global function like without using the `var` but is there any better way to do it? I have `$(document).ready(function(){});`  layout.html and `$(document).ready(function(){});` order.html. I want to make a function in layout.html that can be reuse in order.html, but not other htmls.

Comment: You can define it in a `common_utilities.js` and import it in both html files

Comment: Do `window.myModule = /* whatever you want to put in your module */`. Don't declare variables without `var`: it's forbidden in strict mode (which you should be using IMO), and it can become confusing.

Comment: I'm little curious to know how making it global is solving the problem? Is it an SPA?

Comment: @Rajesh no, I don't use any framework

Comment: @AliciaBrandon then I guess you should use utility file and import it where ever required. Also note, its a bad practice to use global variables. You should try to avoid it and if no options then only use them. Under such circumstances, instead of removing `var` you should use `window.variableName` and use it as `window.variableName`. This will signify its a global variable and someone does not have to read all your code to understand this. Hope it helps.